# Create a bar plot in ggplot where the width of bars is associated with a variable

Tags: r, ggplot2, bar-chart

I am trying to create a bar chart in ggplot where the widths of the bars are associated with a variable (Cost$Sum.of.FS_P_Reduction_Kg). I am using the argument `width=Sum.of.FS_P_Reduction_Kg` to set the width of the bars according to a variable.

When I try this there appears to be a residual bar width showing on the x axis either side of my data. Any help would be much appreciated.

I have used the following code:

```
# Plotting a bar plot
P <- ggplot(data=Cost, 
            aes(x = reorder(Row.Labels, 
                            Average.of.Cost_Per_Kg_P_Removal.undiscounted.), 
                y = Average.of.Cost_Per_Kg_P_Removal.undiscounted.))+      
  geom_bar(aes(width = Sum.of.FS_P_Reduction_Kg), 
           stat="identity", position="stack") + 
  labs(x="Breed",
       y="Hypothetical budget allocation (million)",
       fill="") +
  theme_bw() + 
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(size=12, angle=50, vjust=0.9, hjust=0.9),
        axis.text.y = element_text(size=12, angle=0, vjust=0.9, hjust=0.9),
        axis.title = element_text(size=12),
        panel.grid.major = element_blank(),
        panel.grid.minor = element_blank())
P
```

The example data table can be reproduced with the following code:

```
> dput(Cost)
structure(list(Row.Labels = structure(c(12L, 7L, 1L, 13L, 5L, 
2L, 4L, 9L, 11L, 10L, 3L, 6L, 8L), .Label = c("Arable reversion to grassland", 
"Below ground storage tank", "Farmer innovation", "Hard but permeable base for livestock trough", 
"Inspection pit / chamber", "Livestock and machinery hardcore track", 
"Livestock trough and associated pipework", "Outdoor concrete yard renewal", 
"Post and wire", "Rainwater goods (e.g. downpipes and gutters)", 
"Sheep netting", "Take small areas out of management", "Underground drainage pipework"
), class = "factor"), Sum.of.FS_P_Reduction_Kg = c(12.64101786, 
0.176600362, 55.72340816, 3.703855174, 0.720092872, 2.706349044, 
0.147201968, 2.384, 4.172, 0.902116348, 0.484584083, 2.804297297, 
7.318418487), Average.of.FS_._Change = c(7.512500968, 0.171350352, 
15.57475304, 1.134677581, 0.427948007, 1.373840031, 0.087481478, 
1.416800649, 2.009493261, 1.09895273, 0.213553091, 1.86688413, 
0.855936243), Average.of.Cost_Per_Kg_P_Removal.undiscounted. = c(2.803262345, 
39.60180868, 62.83192667, 89.73898667, 117.1877639, 140.2541905, 
142.5326142, 148.4987396, 204.7318937, 205.9310466, 482.1676716, 
642.6339007, 1645.812466), Average.of.STW_Treatment_Cost_BASIC = c(155.1394461, 
155.1394461, 155.1394461, 155.1394461, 155.1394461, 155.1394461, 
155.1394461, 155.1394461, 155.1394461, 155.1394461, 155.1394461, 
155.1394461, 155.1394461), Average.of.STW_Treatment_Cost_HIGH = c(286.0340149, 
286.0340149, 286.0340149, 286.0340149, 286.0340149, 286.0340149, 
286.0340149, 286.0340149, 286.0340149, 286.0340149, 286.0340149, 
286.0340149, 286.0340149), Average.of.STW_Treatment_Cost_INTENSIVE = c(1109.93418, 
1109.93418, 1109.93418, 1109.93418, 1109.93418, 1109.93418, 1109.93418, 
1109.93418, 1109.93418, 1109.93418, 1109.93418, 1109.93418, 1109.93418
)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -13L))
```

I am trying to create a replica of the following accept in ggplot:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can space out the bars properly (while retaining their different bar widths) by placing each one in its own facet, & setting both scale / space to vary freely:

```
ggplot(Cost,
       aes(x = Row.Labels,
           y = Average.of.Cost_Per_Kg_P_Removal.undiscounted.,
           width = Sum.of.FS_P_Reduction_Kg)) +
  geom_col(fill = "grey", colour = "black") + # geom_col is equivalent to geom_bar with
                                              # stat = "identity", & position = "stack"
                                              # is the default anyway, so no need to state it.
  facet_grid(~reorder(Row.Labels, 
                      Average.of.Cost_Per_Kg_P_Removal.undiscounted.), 
             scales = "free_x", space = "free_x") +
  labs(x = "Breed",
       y = "Hypothetical budget allocation (million)") +
  coord_cartesian(expand = FALSE) +     # remove spacing within each facet
  theme_classic() +
  theme(strip.text = element_blank(),   # hide facet title (since it's same as x label anyway)
        panel.spacing = unit(0, "pt"),  # remove spacing between facets
        plot.margin = unit(c(rep(5.5, 3), 50), "pt"), # more space on left for axis label
        axis.text.x = element_text(size=12, angle=50, vjust=1, hjust=1))
```

[image: plot]

Comment: This is really useful - thanks. Is there a way to stop the text over lapping on the x axis labels?

Answer (score 3):

This looks like a histogram with variable bin widths. If you had the raw data from which your sums and averages were calculated, you could use `geom_histogram` with the "binwidth" argument. Unfortunately it's difficult to replicate this plot with the summary data alone, but here's an attempt. We can calculate the boundaries of each rectangle and then use `geom_rect` to plot them.

```
library(tidyverse)

Cost.new <- Cost %>% 
  mutate(
    xmin = cumsum(lag(Sum.of.FS_P_Reduction_Kg, default = 0)),
    xmax = cumsum(Sum.of.FS_P_Reduction_Kg),
    ymin = 0,
    ymax = Average.of.Cost_Per_Kg_P_Removal.undiscounted.,
    label.pos = (xmin + xmax) / 2
  )

ggplot(data = Cost.new) +
  geom_rect(aes(xmin = xmin, xmax = xmax, ymin = ymin, ymax = ymax), fill = 'white', color = 'black') +
  scale_x_continuous(breaks = Cost.new$label.pos, labels = Cost.new$Row.Labels) +
  theme(axis.text.x=element_text (size=12, angle=45, vjust=1, hjust=1),
        axis.text.y=element_text (size=12),
        axis.title=element_text(size=12),
        panel.grid.major = element_blank(),
        panel.grid.minor = element_blank())
```

[image]

Comment: Hey, I am using your code with my dataframe, but it does not respect the width of the bars. I cannot ask a question (problem with profile), but what could be the reason for this problem?

Comment: Impossible to say without a sample of your data.

Comment: [link](https://stockholmuniversity.box.com/s/0qal4gkdd1m4qf78oknvet0zr41clpdx) Attached the data